# React Highcharts Treemap - customize Tooltip with React component

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to use Highcharts Treemap in my React app.
And I want to change the tooltip to be able to render React components there (JSX.Element, at least). The docs say

"A subset of HTML is supported. Unless `useHTML` is true, the HTML of the tooltip is parsed and converted to SVG, therefore this isn't a complete HTML renderer. The following HTML tags are supported: `b`, `br`, `em`, `i`, `span`, `strong`. Spans can be styled with a `style` attribute, but only text-related CSS, that is shared with SVG, is handled."

Do someone know of any workaround to render a little bit more advanced tooltips?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use JSX in Highcharts formatters, but there are several other solutions:

- create a separate component for tooltip and position it relative to a chart container
- create empty Highcharts tooltip and use React portals to render React component in it
- use `renderToString` or some other method from `ReactDOMServer` to convert JSX to HTML

Please check this thread for more information and examples: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/23

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-react-component-to-a-charts-element

Comment: Thank you!I currently try following the solution with React portals.
A small issue I encountered: In the examples I found in your resources, you (and others) use point.dataLabel as the second param to createPortal. From what I see now, we no longer have this attribute.. what replaced it? I don't find anything I can provide as dom element. Should I query the dom directly? (document.... etc.) @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @B. Grossman, You can still refer to a data-label by using: `dataLabel` point's property. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fy09pa8w/

Comment: I see that even in this example, if you add in the end '.div' (so 'dataLabel.div'), you get undefined. unlike the previous examples..
And I still get this error in my project:
Property 'dataLabel' does not exist on type 'Point'. @ppotaczek

Comment: That's because you need to enable `useHTML` option. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zo75batd/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels. Also, please try to use: `chart.series[0].points[0].dataLabels[0].div`, to fix the TS error.